# Unable to See Protocol In Preferences or Enabled Protocols using LUA in Wireshark

Tags: lua, zeromq, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I have imported a lua script into Wireshark with the intention of decoding 0mq/ ZeroMQ packets into ZMTP:

Whilst I CAN use the ZMTP filter successfully... AND the ZMTP protocol is "Enabled" within the protocols...

Furthermore, in the internals, I can see the dissector table and that it is a supported protocol..

However... it does not appear in "Preferences".

Therefore (I am making the assumption) that this it doesn't appear in the "Decode As Function"

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using the current master (commit hash `04d3c65498b1c4ec6069cb27750dfa6e5b9b1332`).  I was having the same problems.  I actually went back one commit (to `0702cc445cc80cdec55305c46fc2f97db9c00075`) and now ZMTP shows up in "Decode As".

Answer (score 0):

It is not really an answer as to why it is not in the "Decode As" function. I'm having that exact problem, I've installed the plugin https://github.com/whitequark/zmtp-wireshark but I cannot decode as ZMTP.

However I can answer your question regarding the absence of ZMTP in the preferences. It has simply been removed because there is no need for it anymore [according to the last commit](https://github.com/whitequark/zmtp-wireshark/commit/04d3c65498b1c4ec6069cb27750dfa6e5b9b1332). Normally, the "Decode As" function should work, so there should not be a need for it...

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me at least! I've had the same behaviour on both Linux and Windows.. So not sure what else to try in all honesty?! If you have any luck please le me know